# JS Function designed to return elements to React component not returning properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to check a set of data to see if a string has a particular prefix or suffix and then return the string broken up into `<span>` elements. The function I have written correctly matches the parts of teh string with the relevant morphemes in my data set but doesn't return the spans split up.

Currently it returns something like this:

```
<span></span>
<span>word</span>
<span></span>
```

Im not sure what i am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
export const morphemeCheck2 = (word) => {
  return (
    <span>
      <span>{prefixCheck(word)}</span>
      <span>{suffixCheck(word)}</span>
      <span>{baseWord(word)}</span>
    </span>
  )
}

const prefixCheck = (x) => {
  api.getPrefixes().then((data) => {
    let prefixes = data
    for (let p = 0; p < prefixes.length; p++) {
      let prefix = prefixes[p].affix_name
      if (x.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return (
          <span className={'suffix ' + prefix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
            {prefix}
          </span>
        )
      }
    }
  })
}

//needs refactoring
const baseWord = (x) => {
  if (prefixCheck(x) && suffixCheck(x)) {
    const prefix = prefixCheck(x)
    const suffix = suffixCheck(x)
    const prefixLength = prefix.props.children.length
    const suffixLength = suffix.props.children.length
    const tail = x.length - suffixLength
    return x.substring(prefixLength, tail)
  } else if (prefixCheck(x)) {
    const prefix = prefixCheck(x)
    const prefixLength = prefix.props.children.length
    return x.substring(prefixLength, x.length)
  } else if (suffixCheck(x)) {
    const suffix = suffixCheck(x)
    const suffixLength = suffix.props.children.length
    const tail = x.length - suffixLength
    return x.substring(0, tail)
  } else {
    return x
  }
}

const suffixCheck = (x) => {
  api.getSuffixes().then((data) => {
    let suffixes = data
    for (let s = 0; s < suffixes.length; s++) {
      let suffix = suffixes[s].affix_name
      if (x.endsWith(suffix)) {
        console.log(suffix)
        return (
          <span className={'suffix ' + suffix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
            {suffix}
          </span>
        )
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here is where it is called in the React component:

```
const AnalysisArea = () => {
 [...]

  let text = "recoded"

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Card className="analysisframe">
        <p className="replicated-text" onClick={handleOpen}>
          {decoder.morphemeCheck2(text)}
        </p>
      </Card>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from `prefixCheck` and `suffixCheck`. Inside those two functions you just executed async call and did nothing with the result(no return statement inside function). I advise you to rewrite in async/await manner(because of readability) and, of course, to return desired result from those functions. If you need more help(to rewrite those functions) feel free to reach.

**UPDATED WITH EXAMPLE OF REFACTORED FUNCTIONS**
Key point is to wait for the response in order to use that response of your async call and do something with it(return something based on api call response).

```
   const suffixCheck = async (x) => {
     const data = await api.getSuffixes(); // You need to await in order to get data that you want to use in order to return something
     let suffixes = data
     for (let s = 0; s < suffixes.length; s++) {
       let suffix = suffixes[s].affix_name
       if (x.endsWith(suffix)) {
         console.log(suffix)
         return (
           <span className={'suffix ' + suffix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
             {suffix}
           </span>
         )
       }
     }
     return '';
  }

    

const prefixCheck = async (x) => {
  const data = await api.getPrefixes();
  let prefixes = data
  for (let p = 0; p < prefixes.length; p++) {
    let prefix = prefixes[p].affix_name
    if (x.startsWith(prefix)) {
      return (
        <span className={'suffix ' + prefix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
          {prefix}
        </span>
      )
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I am reasonably new to this, it would be helpful to have an example of what you mean?

Comment: My confusion is that I thought this was the "return": ``return (
          <span className={'suffix ' + prefix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
            {prefix}
          </span>
        )``

Comment: I have update my comment with refactored solution.